# Using "have" in sentences

Tags: past-tense, causative-have

I was writing an email today and caught myself having difficulty to decide which of the sentences is most suitable:

- I **have** noticed that you already replied to the other emails.
- I noticed that you **have** already replied to the other emails.
- I noticed that you already replied to the other emails.

Which of the sentences above is correct? Is the usage of "have" in them ok?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As FumbleFingers said, there's a 4th permutation which goes like:

I have noticed that you have already replied to the other emails. (with two haves in both positions you would insert the word 'have', first and second  sentences combined.)

All four sentences are grammatically correct, but when I am writing an email I tend to write about what's happening currently.

For myself, I would use "I noticed that you have already replied to the other emails.", while "I noticed that you already replied to the other emails." is also fine.

If you were to say "I have noticed you already replied to the other emails.", it sounds like something like a supervisor for me when someone has been watching for a long period of time.

Comment: Without **have noticed**, there is also no reason why the sentence can't start with the present tense **I notice**. The way I would naturally express it is ***I notice*** *that you* ***have*** *already replied to the other emails.*